# initialize variable repeatedly using for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, loops, for-loop, initialization

my question is can i possibly initialize variables repeatedly (with changing only numbers after them) this is my code

```
for(i = truStorage.getItem('elementCount'); i>0; i--) {
var obj = truStorage.getItem("element_" + i);
var [obj_+i] =  element(erd.Entity , obj.posx, obj.posy, obj.text );}

};
```

basically i just want to initialize a variable like

```
something_i = "";
```

and the result will be like this

```
var element_1 = element(erd.Entity, 100, 200, "Employee");
var element_2 = element(erd.Entity, 100, 400, "Salesman");
var element_3 = element(erd.WeakEntity, 530, 200, "Wage");
var element_4 = element(erd.IdentifyingRelationship, 350, 190, "gets paid");
```

im not trying to use variables as a storage but rather to instantiate an element for a function.

Comment: Why you no use `Array`?!?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? This sounds like a bad idea, maybe we can help you with ideas :)

Comment: Everytime you come across a situation like that, just push all your objects into an array and iterate over it.

Comment: i have edited the code.. hope it explains it much better

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for an array.

```
var something = [];
var somethings = 5;

for(var i = 0; i < somethings; i++) {
    something[i] = "";
}
```

You should now be able to access the five values like this:

```
console.log(something[0])
console.log(something[1])
console.log(something[2])
console.log(something[3])
console.log(something[4])
```

Notice you use 0 to access the first element. That's just how it is because JavaScript arrays are zero-based.

Answer (score 0):

This is best scenario to use array:

```
var counter=0,something = new Array();
for(i = truStorage.getItem('elementCount'); i>0; i--) {
   something[counter] =  truStorage.getItem("element_" + i).text;
   counter++;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for(var i=1; i<=4; i++) {
    this["something_" + i] = i;
}

console.log(something_1); //outputs 1;
console.log(something_2); //outputs 2;
console.log(something_3); //outputs 3;
console.log(something_4); //outputs 4;
```

Note: using an array will be faster!

Comment: 1: use window, not this (which can change with scope and is not defined at root level in strict mode) and 2: the other questions are providing a much better answer to the *problem* (if not the question); you should at least note that.